# MYSQL select with 2 dates condition

Tags: php, mysql

In my database, I have 2 different dates. A move date and a event date. I would like to run a query by event date. But if there is no event date, so i want use the move date. Is there a MYSQL code that does this? Like this: "where if .." Of course the result is in descending order date. Thanks !

Comment: please post few data and your desired output

Comment: use if/else statement

Comment: Maybe `coalesce` something like `where coalesce(eventdate, movedate) >= ?` not a PHP question though

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this

Answer (score 1):

try this one like where coalesce(event_date, move_date) >= ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

use the "case" condition

SELECT CASE WHEN movedate != NULL THEN movedate ELSE eventdate END AS selecteddate